# CSS and jQuery current links navigation: how to update the <li> class

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I have this jQuery code that retrieves external content using ajax, without refereshing the page, and I also have a navigation links that has the different background color when user is on the current page.

The jQuery code:

```
function loadPage(url)  //the function that loads pages via AJAX
{
    url=url.replace('#page','');    //strip the #page part of the hash and leave only the page number

    //$('#loading').css('visibility','visible');    //show the rotating gif animation
        $('.counter').html('<img src="img/ajax_load.gif" width="16" height="16" style="padding:12px" alt="loading" />');

    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,  //with the page number as a parameter
        dataType: "",   //expect html to be returned
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)    //if no errors
            {
                $('#change-container').html(msg);   //load the returned html into pageContet


            }
        }

    });
}
```

the html navigation code:

```
<ul>
   <li class="current"><a href="#page1">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#page3">Replies</a></li>
   <li><a href="#page4">Favorites</a></li>
</ul>
```

So basically when someone clicks on the replies link, I want the `li` class to change to current, to indicate that you are at that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/4cs9h/

```
$('ul > li > a').click(function() {
    var $th = $(this).parent();
    if( !$th.hasClass('current') ) {
        $th.addClass('current')
               .siblings('.current').removeClass('current');
        loadPage(this.href);
    }
    return false;
});
```

The `$th` variable refers to the parent `<li>` of the `<a>` that was clicked.

If the `<li>` does *not* have the `current` class, the class will be added and will be removed from any siblings that have that class, and `loadPage()` will be called, sending the `href` attribute of the clicked `<a>`.

---

With regard to your comment, yes it would be a good idea to target the specific `<ul>` with an ID.

```
$('#navigation > li > a').click(function() {...
```

HTML

```
<ul id="navigation">
   <li class="current"><a href="#page1">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#page3">Replies</a></li>
   ...
```

---

To use a hash value included in the page, you can pass it to the `loadPage()` function.

```
var hash = window.location.hash;

    if( !hash || hash === '#' )
        hash = "#page1";

loadPage( hash );
```

Comment: thanks for the great answer would it better to give the ul a class or an id!! and how can put that on the jquery code you provides, so it only targets the ul list that i want i.e. #navigation

Comment: @getaway - I'd definitely place an ID on the `<ul>` so you target that specific one. I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks, can i just ask where shall i put that on my jquery code above, so basically when it loads then you can current the link

Comment: @getaway - Do you mean when the page loads with a `hash` in the URL? You could pass the hash, or a default value to `loadPage()`. I'll update.

Comment: @getaway - I see there may be another issue. In the `click` handler, instead of `loadPage(this.href);`, try `loadPage(this.hash);`.

Comment: oh my god how did you know that was already on my page!!! the whole jquery code is here http://jsfiddle.net/bKbh3/ can you please check it out, and see whats the problem +up vote for you :))

Comment: @getaway - You need to remove the click handler out of the `success:` callback, and add it at the top in place of the other click handler. I also changed it to use `this.hash`. Here's an update: http://jsfiddle.net/bKbh3/3/

Comment: @patrick thanks, but its still not working!!! the page loads fine, but the current attribute is not moving to replies, it stays at the home link

Answer (score 1):

This will work for what you want, with limitations:

```
$('ul a').click(
    function(){
        $('.current').removeClass('current');
        $(this).addClass('current');

        return false;
    }
);
```

The problems are:

1. No `id` for the parent `ul`, so *this* (presumably navigation) `ul` is no different from any other on the page,
2. This means that if *any* link (`a`) within *any* `ul` is clicked that link will get the `current` class-name. This may be what you want, but I wouldn't recommend it, it's too easy to end up with unwanted behaviour.

#### Suggestion:

Give the parent `ul` an `id` (that way it's identified *uniquely* on the page), for example 'navigation', this allows the jQuery to become highly selective.

```
$('#navigation a').click(
  function() {
    $('.current','#navigation').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');
    return false;
  }
);
```

This also partially addresses the concerns raised by @Alec in the comments, as the `id` provides a unique context in which to search for the `.current` element, preventing effects from being scattered around the page.

Comment: Targeting `$('.current')` means that every element (also outside this menu) with the class 'current' will have its class removed. It's better to target e.g. `$(this).closest('ul').find('li.current')`. And `$(this)` refers to the `a` element, not the `li`, so that should be `$(this).parent()`.

Comment: @Alec, agreed. I never mentioned that in the first instance, because I felt it was my fault for not coming up with something as scarily-efficient looking as @patrick (I'm simple folk, still, sadly). But it *is* one of the benefits I mention following the **suggestion**.

Comment: David - You should remove the `>` from your first solution, because it is a [`child-selector`](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) and there are no `<a>` elements that are a direct child of `<ul>`. :o)

Comment: @patrick, yeah, I...gosh. I originally used `$('ul > li > a')` as the selector, and edited it to remove the `li`...apparently leaving one of the `>`s behind. Oops. Thanks =)